# Magento get order shipping method title

Tags: magento

Hi can anybody tell me how can i get after successfully order is placed shipping method title?

Here is what i have

```
$iOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($iOrderId);

echo $oOrder->getShippingMethod();
```

but how can i get this shipping method title?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$oOrder->getShippingDescription();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($iOrderId);
$order->getShippingDescription();
```

Or

```
$shipping = $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
echo $shipping->getData('title');
```

Comment: `gettype($order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod())` returns null

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when looking for the custom title:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId)->getTracksCollection()->getFirstItem()->getTitle();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$order->getShippingDescription(); // returns Shipping Method Title
```

Comment: For checkout page what event need to use, check what are all the shipping methods available before place an order. @Nitesh

Comment: @Gem Please try with this event "checkout_cart_save_after" and let me know is it worked?

Comment: Here is my observer -> log testing not generated, https://paiza.io/projects/94Pe8vp1jgdXXepLxUDzfQ could you pls help me.

Comment: @Gem ohhh its magento 1, I am sorry for that I don't know about it